# ToString Method called on value types C#

Tags: c#, oop

```
    One hh = new();
    Console.WriteLine(hh.ToString());
    Int32 ww = 77;
    Console.WriteLine(ww.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(5.ToString());
```

I have the `One` class which does not override the ToString method and so its instance: hh returns One when I call It which is fine.
I am just trying To ubderstand why do not the `ww.ToString()` or `5.ToString()` return like Int32 , but instead they return 77 and 5?

As I understand there is `Boxing` going on here.
I mean obviously ww and 5 are not objects but Int32 derives the Object class implicitly. Can you please help me? I am really confused here.

Comment: Every C# type has the opportunity to override `ToString` inherited from `Object`, and that is what `Int32` does: [Int32.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-int32-tostring). For the same reason, `String.ToString()` doesn't return "String", etc. You chose not to override `ToString()` in `One`, but you could have done so and have it returned e.g. "Two" instead.

Comment: Okay, I see, so does It mean. that if the type does not override the ToString(), then when called, their type is returned?

Comment: There's no boxing happening here - boxing is when a struct (a value type) is put on to the heap - for example via doing `(object)1`. Here you're calling an instance method on a struct type - specifically one defined as `public struct Int32` - and that operates directly on the stack. The resulting string is heap allocated though.

Comment: @Jason9789 [Yes :)](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/object.cs#L52) ToString is a virtual method on the Object class. Not overriding it will make it return the type name instead by default.

Comment: Wait a minute, If there is no boxing, how am I able to call 5.ToString() ?  5 is not an object. How can a value type call a method?

Comment: Under the hood a Type is essentially a collection of methods and a description of its structure in memory - That includes `Object` and `Int32`. When you run thing.ToString(), the dotnet runtime knows it needs to locate the ToString method (either an overriding version of it, or the original), and pass it some sort of reference so that it can correctly operate on `thing`. In the case of `5.ToString()`, the runtime literally passes the `ToString()` method an address on the stack as the "this" value.

Comment: Here's the opcodes in intermediate language (IL) that `5.ToString()` compiles to: `ldc.i4.5   stloc.s 1   ldloca.s 1   call instance string [System.Runtime]System.Int32::ToString()`. This means "load a constant 5. Store it in stack local #1. Load the address of stack local #1. Invoke the instance ToString() method". When invoking instance methods, the first arg on the stack is the value that will be used as `this` by the method itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your question caused me to go down the rabbit hole of calling a parent virtual method from outside the class hierarchy. It is possible to call `Object.ToString()` on any type by generating your own IL.

With these extension methods and class wrapper, you can do it.

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public static class Object_Ext {
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsSingleton<T>(this T item) => new[] { item };

    public static IEnumerable<T> FollowedBy<T>(this T first, IEnumerable<T> rest) => first.AsSingleton().Concat(rest);
}

public static class DynamicMethodExt {
    public static T CreateDelegateFor<T>(this DynamicMethod dm, T _) where T : Delegate => dm.CreateDelegate<T>();
}

static class Object_ToString_Ext {
    private static Func<object, string> Object_ToString_Fn;

    public static string Object_ToString<T>(this T obj) => Object_ToString_Fn(obj);

    static Object_ToString_Ext() {
        var m = typeof(Object).GetMethod("ToString");
        var dm = new DynamicMethod("", m.ReturnType, m.DeclaringType.FollowedBy(m.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType)).ToArray(), m.DeclaringType);
        var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, m);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        Object_ToString_Fn = dm.CreateDelegateFor(Object_ToString_Fn);
    }
}
```

Now if you do `5.Object_ToString()` and then return value will be `System.Int32`.